# Increase margins from table line to text

Tags: tables

[image]

In the following tables I'm trying to increase the margins of the two lines below the years (1881 and 1907) so that the text (inhabitants...., km2....) is not so near to the lines. I can't seem to find a suitable solution without completely having to overhaul the design of the table. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{bigstrut}
\makeatletter
\def\hlinewd#1{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
    \hline
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1881} &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1907} \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-3}\cline{5-6}    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Nation} & \shortstack{Inhabitants\\ per association} & \shortstack{km\textsuperscript{2}\\ per association} &       & \shortstack{Inhabitants\\ per association} & \shortstack{km\textsuperscript{2}\\ per association} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Switzerland} & 21'850 & 348   &       & 4'845 & 61 \bigstrut[t]\\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Germany} & 25'367 & 323   &       & 7'960 & 84 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Netherlands} & 76'000 & 660   &       & 30'303 & 167 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Belgium} & 81'818 & 446   &       & 33'488 & 137 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Sweden} & 173'077 & 17'337 &       & 39'901 & 12'879 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{France} & 205'555 & 2'980 &       & 144'743 & 529 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Italy} & 301'087 & 3'116 &       & 296'962 & 2'704 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion that doesn't require redesigning the tabular material: load the `booktabs` package, and replace the two `\cline` instructions with `\cmidrule` instructions.

Separately, do please remove the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` "wrappers" from the cells in the left-hand column -- its cell alignment is `l`, so the wrappers are entirely redundant.

The following code implements these ideas, uses `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` instead of the generic `\hline`s, dispenses with the `\bigstrut` directives, and also gets rid of the extra, blank column in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % a handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1881} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1907} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}   
       & \mc{Inhabitants} & \mc{km\textsuperscript{2}} & \mc{Inhabitants} & \mc{km\textsuperscript{2}} \\
Nation & \mc{per association} & \mc{per association} & \mc{per association} & \mc{per association} \\
\midrule
Switzerland & 21'850  & 348    &  4'845 & 61 \\
Germany     & 25'367  & 323    &  7'960 & 84 \\
Netherlands & 76'000  & 660    & 30'303 & 167 \\
Belgium     & 81'818  & 446    & 33'488 & 137 \\
Sweden      & 173'077 & 17'337 & 39'901 & 12'879 \\
France      & 205'555 & 2'980  & 144'743 & 529 \\
Italy       & 301'087 & 3'116  & 296'962 & 2'704 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, this table is too wide to fit into a standard-width report-class text block. I haven't made any adjustments in the code above, as I assume you're setting the page geometry appropriately for your document.

Answer (score 3):

Use `booktabs` and `siunitx` for numeric tables.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{A table about inhabitants}\label{tab:inhabitants}

\sisetup{group-four-digits}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3.2pt}% computed after trying

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=6.0]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  S[table-format=6.0]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
&                  \multicolumn{2}{c}{1881} &              \multicolumn{2}{c}{1907} \\
                      \cmidrule(lr){2-3}                      \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
Nation      &   {Inhabitants}   &     \si{km^2}     &   {Inhabitants}   &     \si{km^2} \\
            & {per association} & {per association} & {per association} & {per association} \\
\midrule
Switzerland &  21850 &   348 &   4845 &    61 \\
Germany     &  25367 &   323 &   7960 &    84 \\
Netherlands &  76000 &   660 &  30303 &   167 \\
Belgium     &  81818 &   446 &  33488 &   137 \\
Sweden      & 173077 & 17337 &  39901 & 12879 \\
France      & 205555 &  2980 & 144743 &   529 \\
Italy       & 301087 &  3116 & 296962 &  2704 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The setting to `\tabcolsep` has been computed after seeing that the overfull was about 26pt; there are eight intercolumn spaces to act on

Don't use `'` as a thousands separator in input. You can set it, if you want as output separator in `S` columns (but a thin space is definitely better).

[image]